# Node-Webkit: How to create a file in the local file system?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

With using Node-Webkit, I'm trying to create and write to a text file in a user defined local folder from within a web worker js file. I tried using `requestFileSystemSync()`, `.root.getFile()`, `.createWriter()`, etc. but I'm not sure where this file is saved (can it be written to an defined local folder, or is it "sandboxed" to a special folder location?).

Can anyone offer advice on the best way for me to create text files from a web worker to an arbitrary local folder location? That is, in the local file system outside of a sandboxed file system?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm quite curious what type of application you're writing. If you don't mind me asking, what are the web-workers for and why do you need to write everywhere on the file system?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It sounds like you might be trying to use the web filesystem API. That might be a reasonable solution, it would allow you to run your app as a regular webpage, however the web filesystem API is sandboxed.

node-webkit offers "Complete support for Node.js APIs," which I think means you can use [the node.js file system API](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to write anywhere on the file system. Pretty cool. So something like this should work:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("path/to/anywhere/test.txt", "Hi mom!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Also, [node-webkit web-workers do not support require I hear](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-webkit/ZBD3SVKmPSM).  So you'll need to do your filesystem stuff in your main thread.

Comment: Thanks you for that info and tip. After lots of Googling, I've also concluded that it isn't possible to write to a local file from a web worker. As such, I'll do as you've suggested and do the actual file writing from my main thread. Thanks again!